# Reinstall Reporting Services 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting, ssrs

We are having problems with our reporting services portion of SQL server 2005. Can someone provide some guidance for reinstalling reporting services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just removing the virtual directories from IIS and running the report configuration wizard again?

This is what I have done when our installation went wonky and not only was it quick and painless, it resolved the problem too!

NOTE: We had a security issue where no client could view the reports even when in the correct AD groups

YMMV but you could try this first before going through the entire Add/Remove Programs->Change->Remove Reporting Services->Add/Remove Programs->Change->Install Reporting Services Cycle.....

Comment: You are a genius.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall:
From [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic337658-149-1.aspx):

> Go to Add/Remove Programs and click
>   Change.   Choose Reporting services
>   and continue.   At some point you will
>   have to make the choice to remove SQL
>   server.   Verify that in the blue bar
>   above it says "Reporting Services" and
>   continue.   It's a little
>   nerve-wracking, but that's the way to
>   do it.

Be sure to [backup your encryption key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400729(VS.80).aspx) first!
(If you have encrypted content in your database.)
And as noted by @NYSystemsAnalyst in the comments: also backup your ReportServerDB and ReportServerTempDB databases!

Comment: Be sure to backup the ReportServerDB and ReportServerTempDB databases if you need reports, settings, etc. in there.

Answer (score 1):

Most points are covered in KB [842425](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842425/en-us), aka "How to move a Reporting Services database from a computer that is running Reporting Services to another computer"

Answer (score 0):

I did some SQL downgrading and ran into issues because of this, and created a blog post to help: http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/how-to-move-reporting-services-new-server